# Meteor reactive transform

Tags: meteor

I have a mobile app in development and I'm transforming one of the collections to get the user last seen time, avatar etc.

```
PlayerRecord.prototype = {
    constructor      : PlayerRecord,
    getAssociatedUser: function () {
        return Meteor.users.findOne( this.user_id );
    },
    lastSeenFormatted: function () {
        var user = this.getAssociatedUser();
        return (user && user.last_seen) ? user.last_seen : 'Never';
    }
}
```

My problem is that, if the user last seen returns `Never` initially but then the user is seen, my string return over there is not updated...obviously.

How would you advise me to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether any user had a value for last_seen? This field has to be explicitly published.
According to the Meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user):

> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are
>   published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the
>   current user with:

```
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'last_seen': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

// client
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```